# R markdown PDF does not display the symbols ^ in code chunks correctly

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, pandoc

I am knitting an R markdown to PDF. One of my labels in the plots contains expressions $\times10^23$.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-06-24"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r}
plot(1, type="n", ylab=expression(paste("Count (\u00d7",10^23/L,")")))
```
````

However, the knitted PDF displays a different symbol of 10^23 and 10ˆ23. Copying code will return an error due to this different Unicode symbol.

[image]

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: Interesting problem, confirmed on linux (R-4.2.3). I suspect specifying the verbatim font might be used to fix this, but to be honest I interpret this to be a _bug_, likely in `knitr` or pandoc (or `rmarkdown`?).

Comment: Based on some testing, it looks like the issue is a combination of how Rmarkdown or pandoc translate the '^' character, and how different verbatim environments typeset that representation in the pdf output.  Looking at the `.tex` file, all instances of that character are replaced with `\^{}`.  In text mode and code chunks, this is replaced with a different unicode character that triggers errors in R; in a `verbatim` environment, however, the same character is used.  But Rmarkdown/pandoc use a `Verbatim` environment (from the `fancyvrb` package) to typeset code, which changes the character.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a 'pandoc' tag to this question?  I know it's not mentioned in the question, but I think it is relevant, based on my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## The Short Answer

For reasons I don't completely understand (see below), what solved this issue for me was using xelatex (or lualatex) as the engine to compile the `.tex` file to pdf.

There is a setting in RStudio that supposedly sets this globally in `Tools > Global Options ...`, choose "Sweave" in the left-hand pane, and change the drop-down beside "Typeset LaTex into PDF using:" to "XeLaTeX".

Changing that setting didn't actually change anything when compiling R Markdown files for me ([the default is still pdflatex](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#latex-engine)), but I was able to specify the latex engine in the YAML header of a file by replacing `output: pdf_document` with this:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
```

A pdf produced from a file with this in the header should have the expected caret characters in the R code chunks (and other places, too).

## The Longer Answer

R Markdown outputs to pdf by first running the R code and collecting output (via the `knit()` function), then converting the resulting Markdown to LaTeX (`.tex`) using [Pandoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc), and then compiling the LaTeX file to pdf using a [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) engine (see the [R Markdown documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html) for details).  Both pandoc and the TeX engine (and maybe even the pdf program displaying the file) have a role to play in what character ends up on the screen to be copied.

### What I know

The character we *want* to have in the output, so that we can paste it into the console, is ASCII code 94 (^), which is a "Caret - circumflex" *character*; but what we get from R Markdown's default settings is ASCII code 136 (ˆ), which is a "Modifier letter circumflex accent" - in other words, a *character accent* without a letter underneath.  I don't think this is R Markdown's fault, however.

From what I can tell, Pandoc does a few things that are relevant to how the caret character is treated in the output.  In particular, Pandoc:

- puts all code with syntax highlighting (i.e., the contents of all `r` code chunks with `echo=TRUE`) into a custom `Verbatim` environment from the `favyvrb` package in LaTeX.
- puts all plain code blocks (with no syntax highlighting), including console *output* into a plain `verbatim` environment (LaTeX is case-sensitive, so this is **not** the same as a `Verbatim` environment).
- replaces every instance of the caret ("^") character in a document with `\^{}` in the latex output --- except for the contents of `verbatim` environments (i.e., plain code blocks, including console output), and Math Mode (`$...$`).

  - In Math mode, "^" actually produces an exponent, whereas `\^` is replaced with `\textasciicircum` by Pandoc: this command is not allowed in Math Mode, and the latex engine generates a warning, but continues.  Ironically, in this situation, the output in the pdf is ASCII character code 136, unlike other contexts in a LaTeX document (see below).
  - Note that `\^{}` is not only not allowed in Math Mode, it would cause an error when compiled by the latex engine.  This might be why Pandoc uses `\textasciicircum` in this situation, though there are better alternatives in Math Mode (see links below).

There are many ways to represent this character in latex, and it depends on the context (plain text, verbatim, or Math Mode).  See "[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)" and [this StackOverflow answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77647/10232) for some of the options and details.

`\^{}` and`\textasciicircum` are often presented as 'equivalent' representations in latex, at least in text mode.  But in my experience, it is not always so.  Usually (but not always), I find that with the pdflatex engine, `\^{}` produces an accent character (ASCII code 136, not what we want), whereas `\textasciicircum` produces a caret (ASCII code 94, what we want).
This makes sense to me, given that the `\^{}` command is also used by latex to add a circumflex accent to a letter, by putting that letter in the braces as an argument (e.g., `\^{o}` produces "ô"). So without an argument, the semantic meaning of this command is an accent without a letter.

I also know that XeTeX and luaTeX handle input enconding and fonts differently from pdfTeX.  The fact that changing the TeX engine results in different characters in the output suggests the issue might have to do with fonts, but it could also be how they process the commands themselves.  But that is where my knowledge and understanding run out.

### What I do not know

Why does Pandoc replace "^" with "`\^{}`" instead of "`\textasciicircum`"?  I don't know, but I've asked [the question on the pandoc-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/lgKVdzUnAlo), and I await a reply as of this writing.  *EDIT: is this a bug in Pandoc?*

Why do XeTeX and luaTeX render `\^{}` differently than pdfTeX?  In my limited experience, `\^{}` and `\textasciicircum` can be different when using pdflatex (but not in a 'standalone' document class, which I don't understand why), but they both produce the same output character when using xelatex or lualatex.

Strangely, the entries for ASCII code 94 (table 583) and 136 (table 585) in "[The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)" appear to be reversed: the character appearing beside ASCII character code 94 is actually 136, according to [asciivalue.com](http://asciivalue.com/), and vice versa.  But the characters shown are what is produced by the commands shown: i.e., `\^{}` produces ASCII character code 136 and `\textasciicircum` code 94, despite what the document claims in the tables.  Is this an error in the document, or a bug in pdfLaTeX?  or something else?  Since these are functionally and semantically different ASCII characters, why does this document (and others) claim that "`\^{}`" and "`\textasciicircum`"? are equivalent?

Comment: I am impressed by the quality of your answer and the time you put into drafting it. Cheers. +1

Comment: Thanks @M--, although I feel like I'm left with more questions than answers!  :D At least I stumbled upon a solution that worked for me.  I hope it's helpful to others, too.

Answer (score -2):

The correct code would be as below:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-06-24"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

```{r}
par(mar = c(5, 5, 5, 5)) # Set the margin on all sides to 5
plot(1, type="n", ylab=expression(paste("Count (\u00d7",10^23/L,")")))
```
````

In your code, the power sign shows well in plot label. You only need to set `echo = FALSE`, for not showing your code chunk in R markdown and also you need set some margin for your plot to see ylabel pretty well.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, the post is about code chunks in the knitted PDF displaying 10^23 as 10ˆ23. The most straightforward demo is copying and pasting the latter 10ˆ23 into the console; it returns ``Error: unexpected symbol in "10ˆ23"``.

Comment: As I know, the code chunk appears as it is, but you have more control on writing in LaTeX style text in R Markdown. Maybe below link would help:  https://medium.com/@delucmat/specify-latex-parameters-in-r-markdown-9804467caaf

Comment: This answer avoids the problem, but does not solve it.  In situations where you *want* to show the code, and it contains the power operator (^), readers will not be able to copy & paste the typeset code into R without triggering an Error.